# How can I add multiple controls to a UITableView header section?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder, iad

I have a UISearchDisplayController in the Header section of my UITableView. I would like to display an iAd right above that. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the header section a view containing both the iAd banner and `UISearchDisplayController` as subviews of it.

Comment: You can't add a UISearchDisplayController to a UIView

Comment: Sorry: make the header section a view containing both the iAd banner and `UISearchBar` as subviews of it - a `UISearchBar` can be added to a `UIView` as far as I am aware.

Comment: However, Apple will almost definitely reject your app as a result of the iAd banner being in the header - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719158/will-my-app-get-rejected-if-i-place-an-iad-in-a-uitableview-headerview/3719923#3719923)