# Will my app get rejected if I place an iAd in a UITableView headerView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, app-store, iad

I am displaying iAd's in the headerView of a UITableView. When the user scrolls the iAd disappears because the headerView is no longer visible. I am not sure if this will prevent my app from being accepted.

Comment: i'd like to know in advance, so it doesn't get rejected. looking for knowledgeable folks who can confirm.

Comment: As long as its in the self.tableView.tableHeaderView and not in a section header it will be fine. I have an accepted app that does that. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/core-location-info/id383670716?mt=8

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I explained in an answer to your previous question (and another question that was closed as a duplicate): [iAd appears in simulator but not on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711637/iad-appears-in-simulator-but-not-on-device)

> Apple will reject your application if
>   an iAd is within a table cell. iAds
>   are required to be in a static
>   position on the page, and not in any
>   kind of scroll view (this includes
>   table views). **This is because iAds pay
>   by impression as well as by click, so
>   having an iAd in a table view cell
>   will cause it to be reloaded whenever
>   it scrolls off and on screen again,
>   which could be many times. This would
>   seem like "click-fraud" or similar
>   behaviour**. Apple will not allow this.

I have emphasised the important part of the text.

- iAds **pay by impression** in addition to click.
- Table cells are unloaded/reloaded when scrolled off/on screen.
- Reloading will cause a new request.
- A new request will generate a new impression (if successful).
- A new impression will generate revenue.

In addition to this, iAds in table cells are more likely to be accidentally clicked, because they can move with the table - their position is not fixed.

This section of the Apple iAd Network Contract describes fraudulent behaviour:

> Disallowed artificial enhancements
>   include, but are not limited to, (a)
>   encouraging user Clickthroughs on
>   banners with offers of cash, prizes or
>   anything else of value in exchange for
>   services (collectively,
>   “Inducements”), or **(b) application
>   design that encourages or is
>   reasonably likely to lead to
>   accidental or unintended Clickthroughs
>   by the user (“Unintended
>   Clickthroughs”).**

I have emphasised clause (b) that would apply in this situation.

I am 99.999% certain Apple will reject an application that places iAds in table view cells.

Comment: My ad isn't in a table view cell. a UITableView has a header section and a footer section. I have placed the ad in the Header section (which is not a UITableViewCell, it is actually a UIView).

Comment: Headers get reloaded too.  Anything that scrolls off the screen will get reloaded.  In fact it's worse because table cells get reused; header views do not (as far as I know) unless you specifically implement reuse.  It is VERY EASY to check in the debugger that viewForHeader is called multiple times as you scroll.  I don't know why Jasarein is so wishy-washy - I'm 100% sure such an app would be rejected.  The only good thing would be how quickly the rejection would happen.

Comment: So based on @Jasarien and @Kendall's answers -- the iAd *MUST* be static in one spot that is always visible to avoid being rejected from the App Store?

Comment: I'm glad you finally understand.

Comment: could you provide the link to this Apple's document?

Comment: Kendall, section headers get reloaded but the self.tableView.tableHeaderView does not.

Answer (score 1):

As long as its in the self.tableView.tableHeaderView and not in a section header it will be fine. I have an accepted app that does it: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/core-location-info/id383670716?mt=8