# iPhone - iAds in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, iad

I'm going to put iAd on UITableView in my app, but I'm not sure whether it is a good practice or not. I've read this post [Will my app get rejected if I place an iAd in a UITableView header view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719158/will-my-app-get-rejected-if-i-place-an-iad-in-a-uitableview-headerview) but not sure where the is that Apple documentation (*please see this extract* below) coming from if you know where it is please let me know.

> Apple will reject your application if
>   an iAd is within a table cell. iAds
>   are required to be in a static
>   position on the page, and not in any
>   kind of scroll view (this includes
>   table views). **This is because iAds
>   pay by impression as well as by click,
>   so having an iAd in a table view cell
>   will cause it to be reloaded whenever
>   it scrolls off and on screen again,
>   which could be many times. This would
>   seem like "click-fraud" or similar
>   behaviour.** Apple will not allow
>   this.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine the linked post is going to be correct. The simple way to implement iAds is into a UIViewController - this means that you may consider moving your UITableView into a view controller to accomplish this; the link below describes this process if you are unsure.

I would also like to link you to some of the iAd PDFs but as I am not the team leader of my developer account, and we've not agreed to use iAds yet... I can't do it. But if you do have access then you should have no trouble in finding the exact TOS relating to the ads.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

Comment: Thanks Krypton, I think my question is not clear enough so I've updated it. I've read Ray's tutorial and did implement iAd in my app. I have a UITableView inside a UIViewController and try to put iAd to UITableView' header and footer. I've seen the answer of the post (the link in the question) saying that Apple would reject my app if I do that. I'd like to see the source (citation) of that statement so make sure the information is correct.

Comment: I understand - are you the team leader of your developer account's access? If so, and if you have accepted the iAd terms in iTunes Connect then you will have full access to the iAd TOS and implementation docs, which should give you an answer.